# How can I make unlimited windows using Xcode when developing a Mac app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I am trying to develop an application for the mac however I am having issues trying to make multiple windows such as when you click `cmd+N` on safari.

I have tried looking for tutorials on how to do it however the closest I have got to be able to do this is just by creating a separate window by using this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1Erw7aP0EQ

If anyone knows how I can make unlimited windows using Xcode I will highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a NSDocument-based app, as described in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH1-SW1). BTW, Apple's docs are always worth visiting together with the various tutorials you can dig up with Google.

That said, the document architecture works best if your window is going to contain something that can be viewed as a document. If the `Open...` (and maybe `Save...`) menu items make sense for your data, then you'll likely be fine with the document architecture, otherwise you should be prepared to jump through a few hoops to tweak the architecture to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question however I do not really like apple documentations because I prefer YouTube or simple pieces of code with the explanation because I learn better by listening and watching (hence why I like YouTube tutorials). If you can find a youtube tutorial or add your own simple code that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: @aPyDeveloper you will probably find that SO is not the best place to ask for tutorials or other similar resources. However, you can start a new project in Xcode and make it NSDocument-based. That will already give you the basic structure, but I don't believe there is a way around reading the docs or a book. NSDocument is an architecture, not just a simple class with a few properties.